# Парсинг на php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
echo $text;
?>
```

Суть проблемы в том, что там стоит защита что ли, но в общем не грузится html текст.

С других сайтов получается получить исходный код, а с этого - нет. Вопрос: как на php пропарсить сайт не через `file_get_contents`? В инете рылся, но что-то не нашел подходящего, помогите, пожалуйста. :)

Comment: Всем спасибо. Не думал, что так быстро решится проблема, действительно хороший сайт и грамотные пользователи на нём сидят. Все получилось через CURL и через file_get_contents. В интернете ещё посмотрел http://parsing-and-i.blogspot.com/2009/09/curl.html

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю что за проблемы. Попробуйте curl. Он всё грузит.

**UPD**

Его запросто можно составить. Вот этот всё грузит если заменить example.com на тот, что вы прислали. Только очень важно включить FOLLOWLOCATION чтобы включить follow redirects, иначе будет пустота приходить. Ваш замечательный сайт похоже редиректит сразу без единого слова.

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init("http://exmaple.com");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);      
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: можеш написать примерчик небольшой на curl пажалуйста ато долго везжать :)

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, если не указан User-Agent в заголовке, он перенаправляет куда-то в лес. Такая вот простенькая защита от парсеров.

Изменить отправляемые заголовки можно так:

```
$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'header' => "User-Agent: Nyaaa\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$text = file_get_contents("http://example.com", false, $context);
echo $text;
```

Comment: А, ввиду того, что у меня выскакивала страничка, расположенная на ноуте, который выполняет ныне роль роутера, он перенаправляет на IP-адрес запрашивающего.